# Get XML node value using groovy

Tags: xml, groovy

I'm trying to fetch xml node of one attribute. But its not fetching properly

here is my response

```
def response = "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:ns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/" xmlns:arr="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
<soapenv:Header/>
     <soapenv:Body>
     <tem:getMotorPremium><tem:objUserDetails>                
         <ns:ProductCode>2311</ns:ProductCode>   
        </tem:objUserDetails></tem:getMotorPremium>
     </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I'm trying to fetch productcode from this one

as response["ns:ProductCode"] But this is not returning.

Kindly advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the xml:

```
def xml = '''<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:ns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/" xmlns:arr="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
            |    <soapenv:Header/>
            |    <soapenv:Body>
            |        <tem:getMotorPremium>
            |            <tem:objUserDetails>                
            |                <ns:ProductCode>2311</ns:ProductCode>   
            |            </tem:objUserDetails>
            |        </tem:getMotorPremium>
            |    </soapenv:Body>
            |</soapenv:Envelope>'''.stripMargin()
```

You just need:

```
def code = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xml)
                           .Body
                           .getMotorPremium
                           .objUserDetails
                           .ProductCode
                           .text()
```